# How to limit my Vuetify website max-width to 1440px?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'd like to have my website including v-app-bar and everything limited to max-width 1440px on larger screen, and add a thin bolder to both left and right edges. For the rest of the area outside of the edge, I'd like to add a nice background color or image.

What's the better way to accomplish this idea? I am using Vuetify v2.1.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with plain 'ol CSS

```css
#page {
  background: url(niceimage.jpg);
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#app {
  max-width:1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

where `#app` is your application div, and `#page` is an element that wraps it;